# Powershell Copy all subfolders from network share

Tags: powershell, network-share

After Google page #3 I give up. 
I want to copy all subdirectories of a network share onto another server. Basically I'm doing a "home folder" migration from a QNAP (I know it's a linux OS) to a Windows Server 2016

```
$newPath = "D:\Shares"
$dir = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\srv-nas1" -Directory | ?{$_.PSISContainer}
$exceptions = @("some", "folder", "exceptions", "nothing", "important")
$errors = ""

foreach ($d in $dir){
    $d.Name
    Try{
        if(-not ($exceptions -contains $d.Name)){
            $dirData = $d.FullName
            $adUsername = "DOMAIN\"+$d.Name
            $newSharePath = $newPath + "\" + $d.Name
            $newShareName = $d.Name + "$"

            "[!]Initialized migration for: " + $adUserName

            $Acl = Get-Acl $dirData
            $AdminAr = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("DOMAIN\admin", "FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
            $UsrAr = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($adUsername, "FullControl","ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
            $Acl.SetAccessRule($AdminAr)
            $Acl.SetAccessRule($UsrAr)
            Copy-Item -Path $dirData -Destination $newPath -recurse -Force

            New-SmbShare -Name $newShareName –Path $newSharePath -FullAccess "DOMAIN\admin", $adUsername
            Set-Acl $newSharePath $Acl

            "[+]" + $adUsername + " successfully migrated"
            exit 1
        }
    }Catch{
        "[-]ERROR WTH USER: " + "DOMAIN\"+$d.Name
        $_.Exception
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
        $FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
        $errors += 'ErrorMessage ' + $ErrorMessage + " FailedItem " + $FailedItem + " User " + $adUsername + " `n"
    }
}

$errors
```

Apparently the path to the NAS can not be found when I run the code. I am aware that there might be a conflict because it is a linux and due to the fact im browsing the root path of the share. I also tried to emulate it

```
foreach($Share in Get-WmiObject Win32_Share){
    Get-ChildItem "\\$($Share.__SERVER)\$($Share.Name)"
}
```

But it's a Linux, so it obviously did not work.
Is there any chance I can get it working?

Comment: Use `robocopy.exe`. It's a waste of time to try and re-implement in Powershell what robocopy already does extremely well.

Comment: _from a QNAP (I know it's a linux OS)_ Why should it be problematic for it to be a linux machine?

Comment: @Tomalak Im aware of the existence of robocopy. But the initial question was if this is possible.